# Python text with alpha channel background

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, png, alpha

I'm working with Python 2.7.3 and PIL/Pillow and want to create text (with opacity) on an alpha_channel background saved as png. Here is my code which doesn't do exactly, what I was hoping:

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageDraw
from PIL import ImageFont
from PIL import ImageEnhance

width=854
height=480
opacity=0.8
text='copyright'
filename = 'result.png'
black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)

font = ImageFont.truetype('verdana.ttf',15)
wm = Image.new('RGBA',(width,height),white)
im = Image.new('L',(width,height),0)

draw = ImageDraw.Draw(wm)
w,h = draw.textsize(text, font)
draw.text(((width-w)/2,(height-h)/2),text,white,font)

en = ImageEnhance.Brightness(wm)
#en.putalpha(mask)
mask = en.enhance(1-opacity)
im.paste(wm,(25,25),mask)

im.save(filename)
```

Result:
[image: result]

The following code is what I'm looking for, but the background fully transparent/alpha_channel:

```
import PIL
from PIL import ImageFont
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageDraw

width = 854
height = 480
black = (0,0,0)
text = "copyright"
white = (255,255,255)
font = ImageFont.truetype("Arial.ttf",40)
img = Image.new("RGBA", (width,height),white)
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
w, h = draw.textsize(text, font)
draw.text(((width-w)/2,(height-h)/2),text,black,font=font)
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
#img.putalpha
img.save("result.png")
#img.show
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Which result do you get?

Comment: I added two results as image

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that `wm` has the same color as the text, so you won't see anything if you draw the text onto it. Change the color of `wm` to transparent, like I did below (and remove the commas after initializing of width, height and opacity):

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageDraw
from PIL import ImageFont
from PIL import ImageEnhance

width=854
height=480
opacity=0.8
text='copyright'
filename = 'result.png'
black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)
transparent = (0,0,0,0)

font = ImageFont.truetype('verdana.ttf',15)
wm = Image.new('RGBA',(width,height),transparent)
im = Image.new('RGBA',(width,height),transparent) # Change this line too.

draw = ImageDraw.Draw(wm)
w,h = draw.textsize(text, font)
draw.text(((width-w)/2,(height-h)/2),text,white,font)

en = ImageEnhance.Brightness(wm)
#en.putalpha(mask)
mask = en.enhance(1-opacity)
im.paste(wm,(25,25),mask)

im.save(filename)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but your solution sadly doesn't work. I tested it, but the result is a completely black png file with the "copyright" string as grey text

Comment: Ok, I thought that is what you want. So, how should the picture look like?

Comment: Sorry, I was a bit unclear. The background empty with nothing in there, alpha channel. Then a string in the center of it with a specified opacity.

Comment: Then you have to also set `im` transparent. Look at my update.