# How to create text background in python?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have seen this image, it's like word cloud... and I was wondering how I can create generator like this. My logic is that I need to create background, which I can do in Pillow, after this I need to create background text (this part I don't know how to create), and at the end, I would create a text in front with opacity to make it look like this.

[image]

Is my logic ok? And how to create text background?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thnik that you can use [Image.composite()](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.composite).

This question already has an answer : [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23887765/17601408) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50309414/17601408)